# Как передать данные из inline календаря в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

```js
var myCalendar;
  
  function doOnLoad() {
   
   myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject("calendarHere");
   myCalendar.hideTime();
   myCalendar.show();
   
  }
```

```css
#calendarHere {
   position: relative;
   height: 350px;
  }
```

```html
<body onload="doOnLoad();">
 <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Примерный календарь, 10, 19-22</div>
 <div id="calendarHere"></div>
</body>
```

Собственно вопрос как можно передать данные из inline (Всегда видимого) календаря в PHP как переменную для дальнейшей обработки и работы с базой? А календарь подключается таким образом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны использовать события [onChange](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxcalendar_onchange_event.html) календаря:

```
    myCalendar.attachEvent("onChange", function(date, state){
      $.post('server.php', {date:date}, function(data){
        //нужные операции после ответа с сервера
      });
   });
```

в файле server.php

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
//дальше уже действия с новой датой
```

Все события календаря [здесь](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__refs__dhtmlxcalendar.html)

Comment: Спасибо попробую разобраться хотя ajax у меня хромает немного я бы даже сказал что нормально хромает )

Comment: добавил пост запрос